# SQL - difference and average between more records

Tags: sql, h2

I have the following table COUNTRY_PEOPLE:

```
COUNTRY - CITY - YEAR - PEOPLE

ENGLAND - LONDON 1980 - 7834020
ENGLAND - LONDON 2010 - 8308369
ENGLAND - DERBY  1980 - 231483
ENGLAND - DERBY  2010 - 233700
FRANCE  - PARIS  1980 - 2174654
FRANCE  - PARIS  2010 - 2274880
FRANCE  - NANTES 1980 - 279321
FRANCE  - NANTES 2010 - 290130
```

I need a sql query to get for each country the list of city with the difference between the people in the 2010 and 1980.
So:

```
ENGLAND - LONDON  474349
ENGLAND - DERBY   2217
FRANCE  - PARIS   100226
FRANCE  - NANTES  10809
```

Then the average for country, but this should be easy with a group by.
I just invented the example as translated from a real boring scenario, all data are fake.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 SELECT Country, City, 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Year=2010 THEN People END)-AVG(CASE WHEN Year=1980 THEN People END) as AvgPeople
 FROM COUNTRY_PEOPLE
 GROUP BY Country, City
```

See <kbd>**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/757bb/1)**</kbd>

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please Check below query

```
SELECT a.COUNTRY,a.CITY,(ISNULL(a.PEOPLE,0) - ISNULL(b.PEOPLE,0)) AS PEOPLE
FROM
 (SELECT COUNTRY ,CITY  , SUM(ISNULL(PEOPLE,0)) AS PEOPLE FROM  COUNTRY_PEOPLE
   WHERE [YEAR] = 2010  GROUP BY COUNTRY ,CITY) a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT COUNTRY ,CITY  , SUM(ISNULL(PEOPLE,0)) AS PEOPLE FROM  COUNTRY_PEOPLE 
   WHERE [YEAR] = 1980 GROUP BY COUNTRY ,CITY)
    b ON a.COUNTRY = b.COUNTRY AND a.CITY = b.CITY
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
select c1.Country,c1.City,(c1.People-c2.People) as Diff from Country_people c1
join Country_people c2 on c1.Country = c2.Country and c1.City = c2.City and c1.Year = 2010 `and c2.Year = 1980`
```